# How do you add an arbitrary shortcut to windows 11 start menu "search"?

Tags: windows-11, start-menu

I want to be able to add arbitrary files/executables/shortcuts to the windows 11 `winkey` "start menu searchability"/"pinned apps", regardless of which drive or folder the program is stored on, and regardless of how official the executable is. I've enabled filesystem indexing for search, and tried to include a shortcut to the program in `C:\Program Files\`, but it still doesn't seem to pick up the file in search, and adding third party executables as "apps" seems even more intractible.

Is there a reliable way to do either?

Answer (score 8):

In researching for my question I found that if you add a shortcut to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`, it seems to add the shortcut to the start menu search, and the ability to pin the "app" to the start menu, regardless of the original file's location.

However, by my testing, it doesn't seem any variation of symlink in the start menu folder gives any searchability into the symlinked directories, regardless of search depth.

Comment: I believe this would serve as a better comment or edit to the original post rather than an answer.

Comment: If my question had been asked before, this is what I would've wanted to see as an answer.

Comment: Really?  To me it sounded more like a compromise you settled on rather than an actual answer to the OP, but that could just be me.  I didn't down vote your answer though, so perhaps I'm not the only one who read it that way?

Comment: Also of note: the C:\ProgramData folder is hidden by default. It could also be in a different place. Using the path %ProgramData% in the file explorer path will find it.

Answer (score 5):

I placed the shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and then I was able to find it in "Start - All Applications" and I could "Pin to Start".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).